# Scala code doesnt fetch s3 file

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run an EMR scalding job and the Scala code is suppose to fetch the content of a text file located in an S3 bucket. The `scala.io.source` library is messing up with the correct location of the S3 path.

I am giving the parameter runidfile to the EMR job :

```
--runidfile s3://my-bucket/input.txt
```

The scala code does the following :

```
val runid_path = args("runidfile")
val runid = Source.fromFile(runid_path).getLines().mkString
```

The code somehow doesn't accept the "//" in the S3 path and I get an error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3:/my-bucket/input.txt (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>       at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:90)
>       at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:75)
>       at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:53)
>       at com.move.scalding.userEvents.RecommenderValidator.(RecommenderValidator.scala:37)

Is there any solution or a workaround to this? I tried using `Source.fromURL`, but S3 is not a valid protocol so it doesn't accept it.

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/zengularity/benji

Answer (score 8):

The `scala.io.Source` library is not meant to access files directly from Amazon S3. You need another library for that.

You can use the offical [Amazon S3 Java Library](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/). Here is some sample code (copied together from [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32470705/390808))

```
val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myKey", "mySecretKey")
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("my-bucket", "input.txt"))
val myData = Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent())

val runid = myData.getLines().mkString
```

Comment: Thanks Sven for your reply. I have one more concern. Since I am running it in my professional account, I don't have access to the keys. Moreover, I am running it as a EMR job in the same subnet; so i think it should hit the S3 bucket without any credentials. I would like to know how that would work if you don't mind.

Comment: @RachitRaut I have no experience with Amazon EMR, maybe the documentation could help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-get-data-in.html or you could ask another question.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I followed the sample code provided by Sven and could successfully read a config file from S3. I was using EMR. It works when you create AmazonS3Client() without any credential as long as EMR Role has access to S3 bucket.

Comment: FYI - this method removes newlines. You can just call `myData.mkString` to preserve newlines.