# FileNotFoundException while Unzip file from S3 in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unzip, zip

I am fetching Zip file from S3 and then trying to unzip it.
Zip file contents:-
Test 2 Folder/
    abc.log
    xyz.log

**Code**

```
val S3Object = getObject(id.bucketName, id.key_fileName)
val zipStreamm = new ZipInputStream(S3Object.getObjectContent)

val entryStream = Stream.continually(zipStreamm.getNextEntry).takeWhile(x => x != null)

val files: Stream[String] = entryStream.map { _ =>  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(zipStreamm).getLines.mkString("\n") }
```

**ERROR**

```
Mar 10, 2017 12:48:48 AM com.twitter.finagle.Init$ $anonfun$once$1
INFO: Finagle version 6.42.0 (rev=f48520b6809792d8cb87c5d81a13075fd01c051d) built at 20170203-170145
Mar 10, 2017 12:48:50 AM com.twitter.finagle.util.DefaultMonitor logWithRemoteInfo
WARNING: Exception propagated to the default monitor (upstream address: /127.0.0.1:60721, downstream address: n/a, label: ).
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test 2/abc.log (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from this exception, you are trying to unzip file in **Test 2** folder, not **Test**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test 2/abc.log (Not a directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
```

Can you share code where you execute this operation?

Comment: Am I missing out something?

Comment: No I am using a Finch server. I am testing it locally.   I am getting the file from S3 but dont know Y m facing issues while unzipping it.

Comment: Please consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32629904/3284193

Comment: The Solution works only if there is a single file Not for a Zip file which needs to be unzipped