# How to read a text file in S3 bucket from inside an AWS EMR without using spark

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I need to open a regular text file located in an S3 bucket (NOT a parquet or CSV file) from an EMR cluster. I can directly open CSVs or parquet files directly using `spark.read.parquet("s3://mybucket/some_parq_file")`

But I need to read just a regular text file from EMR cluster using **java.io.File or scala.io.Source**. Get a java.io.FileNotFoundException when I try

```
import scala.io.Source
val hdr = "s3://mybucket/txtfile.txt"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(hdr).getLines) {
    println(line)
}
```

Comment: there is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470705/spark-read-csv-file-from-s3-using-scala

Comment: It's not really answering my question, my EMR cluster already has access to the S3 bucket when I directly use spark. My question is how to access the S3 files in the same EMR cluster without using spark?

Comment: use java sdk. There is no simple way without emrfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that most AWS setup already has the credentials configured in your EMR cluster using the default credential chain and default region provider chain. This should also apply to AWS Lambda. So to access my S3 buckets from EMR cluster, I simply had to use AWSS3ClientBuilder

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, StandardCopyOption}

val bucket ="s3_bucket"
val file_in_s3 = "somefile.txt"
val dest = "/tmp/local_file.txt"
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()
val stream = s3.getObject(bucket, file_in_s3).getObjectContent

Files.copy(stream, new File(dest).toPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. u can give bootstrap script, when the EMR comesup and the bootstrap
   script (.sh file) can access s3 file (i have used this multiple times)
2. u can submit EMR steps, which executes a jar file and the jar may access the s3